# How do I add an "add" button to a tab in a uitableviewcontroller within a uitabbarcontroller?

Tags: xcode, uitabbarcontroller, uitableview, xcode-storyboard

- xcode 4.6
- using Storyboards

When I drag a Bar Button Item to the navigation bar at the top of one of the UITableViewControllers that are children of the UITabBarController xcode creates a new navigation bar at the bottom of the page instead of adding the button where I dropped it.  I would be ok with this, but when I run the app the bottom navigation bar never shows up, so my button is never displayed.

If you need to visualize the app, picture the following:  Root controller displays a list of accounts.  When an account is clicked a tab controller lists tabs for opportunities and contacts.  I need the ability to add opportunities and contacts from the relevant tab

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT
I am not sure if this is the correct solution or not.  I have embedded the uitableviewcontrollers in navigation controllers, which appears to have fixed the problem.

Follow-up question - Is this the correct way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is the correct way to handle this situation.

You should embed the view controller inside a navigation controller by clicking the view controller in your storyboard and using the Xcode menu "Editor" > "Embed In" > "Navigation Controller".